# Best practice: Number of views/clicks over the last 30 days

Tags: php, mysql

I realize that there's a number of ways to do this, so before I get started I wanted some input from some with experience with this kind of task.

I have an MySQL table with 1000s of downloads. Each download has a columb containing the numbers of total downloads.

What I want to do is to make it more dynamic and therefore convert this number into the number of downloads for the last 30 days instead / also.

So I basically I think of making a new table with each download ID and 30 columbs of download data for the last 30 days. Putting these together by PHP and descend by that. Or I could use the "data added" field in the previous meantioned table and divide the total number of downloads with the days the given download has been online.

What solution would you recommend if not a totally different one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That really depends on your exact requirements and system load.

Do you just need the results of thelast month? Run a cronjob resetting this value once a month. If you need a trailing average (always the past 30 days), your mysql approach will certainly work, but 30 fields might be somewhat overkill.

Two solutions:

1. Have 3 fields per downlaod: Todays counter, a blob containing a
   30-element-json array, and todays 30-day-average. A Cronjob
   regularry (at midnight) could move the data fropm the daily counter
   to the array, removing the oldest entry and updating the average.
   That way you would have minimal system load during operation times.
2. Use NoSQL like Redis with daily counters, and give each of them a
   timeout of 30 days. That way you could always summerize whatever
   data you have for a download file, without even touching your
   database.